# '\n' is getting added at the end of each line in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, text, data-extraction

I have a text file `sample.txt` containing data as:

```
Name of Person: John
Age: 24 years
Height: 170 cm
Weight: 64 kg
```

My code is:

```
list_for_dictionary = []
filename='sample.txt'
f = open(filename)

for line_number, line in enumerate(f, 1):
    key="data_values"
    dictionary = {key: {"fileLine": line, "lineNumber": int(line_number), "fileName": filename}}
    list_for_dictionary.append(dictionary)
print(list_for_dictionary)
```

The output which I am getting is :

`[{'data_values': {'fileLine': 'Name of Person: John\n', 'lineNumber': 1, 'fileName': 'sample.txt'}}, {'data_values': {'fileLine': 'Age: 24 years\n', 'lineNumber': 2, 'fileName': 'sample.txt'}}, {'data_values': {'fileLine': 'Height: 170 cm\n', 'lineNumber': 3, 'fileName': 'sample.txt'}}, {'data_values': {'fileLine': 'Weight: 24kgs', 'lineNumber': 4, 'fileName': 'sample.txt'}}]`

My question is why `'\n'` is getting added at the end of each line in `fileLine` and how can I get rid of it?'

Comment: Use line.strip(), \n is a new line. Your file records contains line be line values. That's why you are getting a \n.

Comment: They come out of `for line in f`, or out of `f.readlines()`, that way; it's not "being added" anywhere else, but is *always* part of using an iterator-based interface to read a text file in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `line.strip()` for your `{'fileLine': line.strip()}`